# Assigning an object to C++ array

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, variable-assignment, aggregate-initialization

I'm examining the following code in C++:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Person{
    public:
    int age;
    Person(int age){
        this->age = age;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Person a = Person(2);
    Person temp[] = {a};
    temp[0].age = 5;
    cout << temp[0].age;
    return 0;
}
```

So my guess is that when one assigns an object to a slot of an array in C++, that is equivalent to copying that object into the array.

Thus when we change that element in the array, it won't affect the original object. Is that correct?

Comment: The current code can be said to be correct, you can check it simply by printing logs in the copy constructor and copy assignment operator.
But you must always pay attention to whether a class member does a deep copy or a shallow copy. :D

Comment: I don't see a question here. The code in question prints 5 as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Person temp[] = {a};` is not assignment, but initialization ([aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)):

> Each `direct public base, (since C++17)` array element, or non-static class member, in order of array subscript/appearance in the class definition, is copy-initialized from the corresponding clause of the initializer list.

So `temp` is initialized as containing 1 element, which is copy-initialized from `a` via `Person`'s copy constructor.

And

> when we change that element in the array, it will not affect the original object. Is that correct?

Yes.

---

BTW: `temp[0] = a;` is assignment; `temp[0]` is copy-assigned from `a` via `Person`'s copy assignment operator.

Comment: I see. So if I do ```temp[0] = a```, then the age will actually be changed. I guess what is confusing here is:  a Person array contains consecutive memory blocks with each block holding a Person object. Initially, ```a``` and ```temp[0]``` are in different addresses in memory. Now if I do ```temp[0] = a``` what is ```temp[0]``` holding now? I feel like it cannot hold the actual element ```a``` because it is in another address already.

Comment: @penny Given `temp[0] = a;`, `a` is copy-assigned to `temp[0]`. Note that they're two independent objects.